# how to handle a ModelAndView object with java script

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot

i have a controller that returns a ModelAndView, this controller is called with this script:

```
    document.getElementById('history-equipment').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default anchor tag behavior (e.g., navigating to a new page)

            const url = '/View/Student/History'; // Replace with your API endpoint URL
            var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
            // Request headers
            const headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': token.valueOf() // Replace with your actual access token
            };

            // Request options
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET', // Replace with the HTTP method you want to use (e.g., GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)
                headers: headers
            };

            // Send the request
            fetch(url, requestOptions)
                    .then(response => response.text()) // Use response.text() instead of response.json() to get the HTML content
                    .then(data => {
                        // Handle the response data
                        console.log(data);

                        // Render the returned model and view
                        renderModelAndView(data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        // Handle any errors
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
        });

        function renderModelAndView(htmlContent) {
            // Replace the entire HTML page with the received content
            document.open();
            document.write(htmlContent);
            document.close();
        }
```

and this the html template i want to render:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <!-- icons link-->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

     <!-- custom css link-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/style.css">
    <title>Request Equipment</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <!-- SIDEBAR -->
    <section id="sidebar">
        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="../../static/css/images/logo.png" class="logo-pic"> Smart EMS</a>
        <ul class="side-menu">
            <li><a  href="" ><i class='bx bx-devices icon'></i> Allocation History</a></li>
            <li><a  href="/View/Student/Request" ><i class='bx bx-devices icon'></i> Request Equipment </a></li>
            
        </ul>
        
    </section>
    
    

    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <section id="content">
        <nav>
            <i class='bx bx-menu toggle-sidebar' ></i>
            <form action="#"></form>
            <div id="toggle-btn" class="fas fa-sun"></div>
            <div class="notif">
                <i class="bi bi-bell-fill nav icon" id="bell"></i>
                <ul class="notif-link">
                    <li><a href="#" ><i class="bi bi-bell-fill icon "style="color: green;"></i>check</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="bi bi-bell-fill icon" style="color: green;"></i>check</a></li> 
                    <hr>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="bi bi-bell-fill icon" style="color: green;"></i>check</a></li>       
                </ul>
            </div>
        
            <span class="divider"></span>
            <div class="profile">
                <img src="../../static/css/images/student.png" alt="">
                <ul class="profile-link">
                    <li><a href="Student-ManageMyAccount.html" ><i class="bi bi-person-circle icon"></i>Update info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Login%20&%20Sign-up.html"><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-left"></i> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- MAIN -->
        <main>
            <h1 class="title">Request Equipment</h1>
            <ul class="snippet">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="divider">/</li>
                <li><a href="#" class="active"> Request Equipment </a></li></ul>
            <div class="data">
                <div class="content-data">

                    <!-- data table -->
                    
                    <div class="head">
                        <h3>Equipment Details</h3>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="table-wrapper">
                        <table class="fl-table">
                            
                            
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Item ID</th>
                                <th>Serial number</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>State</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>Content 1</td>
                                <td>Content 1</td>
                                <td>Content 1</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="Student-SendRequestEquipment.html" class="table-button1">Request</a>
                                </td>
                                
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>Content 2</td>
                                <td>Content 2</td>
                                <td>Content 2</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="Student-SendRequestEquipment.html" class="table-button1">Request</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>Content 3</td>
                                <td>Content 3</td>
                                <td>Content 3</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="Student-SendRequestEquipment.html" class="table-button1">Request</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>Content 4</td>
                                <td>Content 4</td>
                                <td>Content 4</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="Student-SendRequestEquipment.html" class="table-button1">Request</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>#</td>
                                <td>Content 5</td>
                                <td>Content 5</td>
                                <td>Content 5</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="Student-SendRequestEquipment.html" class="table-button1">Request</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        
                            
                            <tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                
            
        </main>
        
    </section>
    

     <!--custom js link-->
    <script src="../../static/js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="../../static/js/script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the page is rendered normally, but the functions tied to the buttons stop working, i click and nothing happens. i tried taking the Js from an external file and adding it to the html page itself and that didn't work. i assume it has something to do with eventListeners breaking. So is there anyway way to load the javaScript or refresh the eventListeners?

Comment: Please elaborate your question more. Which functions does not work? How you are calling these functions?

Comment: @HazikArshad all the javascript functions stop working. and these functions are called viw eventListeners. is there a way to return ModelAndView as if calling the controller from an anchor but with JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the problem. it was an issue of eventListeners breaking when the document is rewritten. i replaced the eventListeners with functions that i call from the html file

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting some html code as a string from server. you can try using iframe to embed this code. but first you need to create an html body with iframe in in the document from which you are calling this url.

```
var doc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(htmlContent);
doc.close();
```

Comment: i'm getting a model and view from the server. and i tried the pruposed method but it's the same result, java script functions stop working.

Comment: can you show example of the `htmlContent`

Comment: updated the question to include the view.

Comment: I think the js code from external file is not loaded properly.